# how to get facebook post's total likes with Facebook Api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm trying to get total likes of facebook post. if u use https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID/likes?limit=10000000 for post with 12332 likes it will return json with no more than 5000 objects in it. even with paging it won't count all likes.

Comment: Some objects can be queried for like counts using FQL.  For example, here's a public photo:  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=select%20pid%2Cowner%2Clike_info%20from%20photo%20where%20object_id%3D%2210151179566341749%22